# Crystal Reports 8.5 grouping

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping, user-defined-fields

I am grouping using a formula fCity which goes like this
If {X.MailingCity} > "" Then
{X.MailingCity}
Else
{X.City}
I have two different fields in my view (Home City and Mailing City)

Now, these fields contain many rural communities and in my report I want to have these smaller rural communities included with the major city it is located near.  I created another group (Specified Order) and created the major cities and was attempting to include the rural cities into these groups.  IN the end I ended up with many of the communities in "OTHER" category.  It was only picking up rural communities from the X.MailingCity field and not X.City or from my formula fCity.

Have I just confused you.  If there is someone who understands what I am doing please respond.

Comment: I think you should give an example of how the groupings should look like...

Answer (score 1):

You need to relate rural cities and major cities somehow, then you can just group by major cities (or by formula, returning major city for rural one).